# Is there any special reason for the Donyatsu shoutout in Kogane's backpack?

Tags: bubuki-buranki, donyatsu

In *Bubuki Buranki*, Kogane has a Donyatsu backpack. Written on it above the face of the pastry cat are the words "Not Donyatsu". Is there any special reason (same author, authors were friends, same publisher) for that shoutout?

[image: Dat backpack is 'nuts]
[image: "Not Donyatsu"]

Answer (score 1):

The author/illustrator of *Donyatsu*, [Kozaki Yuusuke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y%C5%ABsuke_Kozaki), is also the lead character designer for *Bubuki Buranki*.